# Trocar todas as palavras em um código HTML

Tags: javascript

Preciso fazer uma função em Javascript que altere todas as palavras encontradas dentro de um site. Tentei algo do tipo:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var txt = elements.replace("Original","Alterada");
    document.getElementsByTagName(i).element.innerHTML = txt;
}
```

Mas infelizmente não deu certo. Aparecem vários erros. Alguma solução?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assim:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var txt = elements[i].innerHTML.replace("Original", "Alterada");
    elements[i].innerHTML = txt;
}
```

Note que essa solução só vai trocar a palavra "Original", e não "original", nem "ORIGINAL", etc.

[Exemplo no jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JdnWh/)

---

Conforme a sugestão do @Kazzkiq, a solução case-insensitive ficaria assim:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var txt = elements[i].innerHTML.replace((new RegExp('(original)', 'gi')), "Alterada";
    elements[i].innerHTML = txt;
}
```

[Exemplo no jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gdHG6/)

Comment: Amigo, perfeito sua resposta. Muito obrigado.

Comment: Para case insensitive: `.replace((new RegExp('(original)', 'gi')), "alterada")`

Comment: Valeu! Atualizei a resposta.